# script to copy some cells to last row of another spreadsheet at specific sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found script that can copy some specified rows to another sheet, which I manage to run successfully. However I want these rows to be copied to the end row of another spreadsheet. I've tried to find other posts so that to adjust these script but couldn't. So could you please help me. (I really have no idea about coding.)

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Copy to catalog')
.addItem('Copy Stuff', 'copyStuff')
.addItem('Create Sidebar', 'createSidebar')
.addToUi();
}

function copyStuff() {
     
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('multiple items'); 
var target= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QaMmElzcCVVOeO8JD-3uCsuY2hkXAxb1x5d0heXcdWM');
var dsh = target.getSheetByName("catalog");
var lastRow = dsh.getLastRow();
var srg=ssh.getRange('A51:X54');

srg.copyTo(dsh.getRange(lastRow));

}

function createSidebar() {
 var html='<input type="button" value="Copy Stuff" onClick="jsCopyStuff();" />';
 html+='<script>function jsCopyStuff(){google.script.run.copyStuff();}</script>';
 var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try:

function copyStuff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName('multiple items');
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QaMmElzcCVVOeO8JD-3uCsuY2hkXAxb1x5d0heXcdWM');
  var dsh = target.getSheetByName("catalog");
  var lastRow = dsh.getLastRow();
  var vs = ssh.getRange('A51:X54').getValues();
  dsh.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: There's an error said : Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet."

Comment: Did it mean it's impossible to copy to the other spreadsheet ?

Comment: I assumed that part was running so I did not pay enough attention to it.  This will work but it will include formatting

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm really no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I did fix it. Is it not running?If so what errors are you getting

Comment: Now the script works! however it seem to replace the current last row's data with the new data.

Comment: I fixed it " dsh.getRange(lastRow+1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);" thank you

Comment: Btw, Can't this script perform copy image-in-cell to the other spreadsheet ? Once i replace text with image , the error occur : "Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets"

Comment: I don't think so.